# Correlate parameters in a type declaration

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I have a generic parser method, that reads data from some source, and converts it into appropriate type. For the sake of example, imagine something like this:

```
 def readStuff[T : Manifest](input: Seq[String]): Т = {
   val constructor = manifest
     .runtimeClass
     .getConstructors
     .head
   val params = constructor
     .getParameterTypes
     .zip(input)
     .map { case (clazz, str) => toType(str, clazz) }
   constructor.newInstance(params).asInstanceOf[T]
 }
```

Now, I'd like to add an ability for the caller to pass in some additional validation/massaging logic, so that I could write something like this:

```
case class Person(
  firstName: String, 
  lastName: String, 
  middleName: String,
  age: Int
)

readStuff[MyStuff](inputs) { 
  case (0|1, s) => require(s.nonEmpty); s
  case (2, s) if s == null => "" 
  case (_, x: Int) => require(x > 0); x
  case x => x
}
```

The problem is how to define the `validator` parameter?
It's would almost look like something like this:

```
def readStuff[T](inputs: Seq[String])(validator: PartialFunction[(Int, Any), Any])
```

*except* that I need to require somehow that first `Any` and second `Any` be the same (albeit unknown) type (so that the output of the validator must be the same type as input).

Any ideas?